# Test class in salesforce using Test.startTest and Test.stopTest

Tags: apex, unit-test

How to write a test class using Test.startTest and Test.stopTest in salesforce. Please give me example of apex class and test class code.

Comment: Please search the developer documentation of Salesforce. It provides answers to most of Why and How's. For your questions, read the following articles :  [Test Methods Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) and [Why use Starttest and Stoptest](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AwXlIAK)

Comment: Just search Test Class using the search box at the top right of this page and you'll find plenty of examples of test classes that have been posted here that users have needed help with. I also highly recommend you visit [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) and go through the Test Class Module if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev Oh yeah, I forgot the trail-head module.

Answer (score 1):

you can write the class as this

```
    static testmethod method1(){
         <your dummy data> 
         test.startTest();
               <main class logic under test>
         test.stopTest();
     }
```

check out this article as well by Shiv http://blog.shivanathd.com/2013/11/Best-Practices-Test-Class-in-Salesforce.html